# Doctrine2: Different behaviours on removing and persisting related Entities

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities `Foo` and `Bar`, `Bar` has a `manyToOne` association to `Foo` called `$foo` and `Foo` has the inverse association, a `oneToMany` association called `$bars` and . And there are **no `cascade` operations** defined on any side. Now my problem is this, if I fetch one `Foo` instance `$foo`, then create and persist some `Bar` instances with `$bar->foo = $foo`, and persist them to the `Entity Manager` and **flush** it, then if I refetch `$foo` from the Repository, `$foo->bars` won't contain the `Bar` instances I just created (unless I call `$entityManager->detach($foo)` first. 
On the other hand if I remove some `Bar` entities related to `$foo` by calling `$em->remove($bar)` and **flush** the `Entity Manager`, then if I refetch `$foo` from the Repository, the `Bar` instances I removed won't be in the `$bars` property anymore. I'll explain more with some code.

```
$foo = $fooRepo->find($id);
$bar = new Bar($foo);
$entityManager->persist($bar);
$entityManager->flush();
$foo = $fooRepo->find($id);
var_dump($foo->getBars()); // $foo->bars won't contain $bar unless I detach $foo first
```

---

```
// Now the other case
$foo = $fooRepo->find($id);
$bars = $foo->getBars();
$bar = $bars[0];
$entityManager->remove($bar);
$entityManager->flush();
$foo = $fooRepo->find($id);
var_dump($foo->getBars()); // this time $foo->bars will reflect the changes we made.
```

I want to know if this is expected Behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanted to comment, but still can't according to my reputation :-(

But I am pretty sure this answers your question: "When a bidirectional assocation is updated, Doctrine only checks on one of both sides for these changes. This is called the owning side of the association."

Check the documentation for associations: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html and especially http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html