# Array Collection not saving to database in manytomany relationship

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a many to many relationship using zend framework 2 and doctrine 2.
The relationship is between categories and products.

My products entity is

```
    <?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Application\Entity\Categories;

/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products", indexes={
 *   @ORM\Index(name="PRIMARY", columns={"product_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="created_by_user_id", columns={"created_by_user_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="retail_status_id", columns={"retail_status_id"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\ProductsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Products extends AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\AttributeSets
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\AttributeSets", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_set_id", referencedColumnName="attribute_set_id")
     * })
     */
    private $attributeSet;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\RetailStatus
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\RetailStatus", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="retail_status_id", referencedColumnName="retail_status_id")
     * })
     */
    private $retailStatus;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=9, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $authUser;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\ProductTitles
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductTitles", cascade={"persist", "persist"}, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\ProductDescriptions
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductDescriptions", cascade={"persist", "persist"}, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\ProductDimentions
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductDimentions", cascade={"persist", "persist"}, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $productDimentions;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categories", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_to_catagory",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="catagory_id", referencedColumnName="catagory_id")}
     * )
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ProductAttributeValues", cascade={"persist", "persist"}, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $values;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($serviceManager);
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\AttributeSets
     */
    public function getAttributeSet()
    {
        return $this->attributeSet;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\RetailStatus
     */
    public function getRetailStatus()
    {
        return $this->retailStatus;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return (bool) $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateModified()
    {
        return $this->dateModified;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getAuthUser()
    {
        return $this->authUser;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\ProductTitles
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\ProductDescriptions
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\ProductDimentions
     */
    public function getProductDimentions()
    {
        return $this->productDimentions;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     */
    public function getValues()
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\AttributeSets $attributeSet
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setAttributeSet(\Application\Entity\AttributeSets $attributeSet)
    {
        $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\RetailStatus $retailStatus
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setRetailStatus(\Application\Entity\RetailStatus $retailStatus)
    {
        $this->retailStatus = $retailStatus;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $price
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param integer $active
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setDateCreated(\DateTime $dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \DateTime $dateModified
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setDateModified(\DateTime $dateModified)
    {
        $this->dateModified = $dateModified;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\Users $authUser
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setAuthUser(\Application\Entity\Users $authUser)
    {
        $this->authUser = $authUser;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\ProductTitles $title
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setTitle(\Application\Entity\ProductTitles $title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\ProductDescriptions $description
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setDescription(\Application\Entity\ProductDescriptions $description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\ProductDimentions $productDimentions
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function setProductDimentions(\Application\Entity\ProductDimentions $productDimentions)
    {
        $this->productDimentions = $productDimentions;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addCategory(Categories $category)
    {
        $this->categories->add($category);
    }

        /**
     * 
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories
     * @return \Application\Entity\Products
     */
    public function addCategories(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $this->addCategory($category);
        }
//        \Freedom\Logger\InfoLogger::vardump($this->categories);
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategories(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->authUser = $this->getAutherizedUser();
//        $this->categories = new PersistentCollection($this->getEntityManager(), NULL, $this->categories);
//        \Freedom\Logger\InfoLogger::vardump($this->categories->count());
//        \Freedom\Logger\InfoLogger::vardump($this->categories);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
//      $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $array = array();
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $var => $value) {
            switch ($var) {
                case 'authUser':
                    if (!is_null($value)) {
                        $array[$var] = $value->toArray();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    $array[$var] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }

}
```

and my category entity

```
    <?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Application\Entity\StaticPages;

/**
 * Categories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="catagories", indexes={
 *   @ORM\Index(name="PRIMARY", columns={"catagory_id"}),
 *   @ORM\Index(name="created_by_user_id", columns={"created_by_user_id"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\CategoriesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Categories extends AbstractEntity
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="catagory_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $catagoryId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by_user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $authUser;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Categories
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categories", inversedBy="childCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_catagory_id", referencedColumnName="catagory_id")
     */
    protected $parentCategory;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Categories", mappedBy="parentCategory")
     */
    protected $childCategories;

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Products", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Sites
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Sites", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id")
     * })
     */
    private $site;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\StaticPages
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\StaticPages", mappedBy="category", cascade="persist")
     */
    private $staticPage;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url_key", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $urlKey;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sort_order", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $sortOrder;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($serviceManager);
        $this->parentCategory = NULL;
        $this->urlKey = NULL;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCatagoryId()
    {
        return $this->catagoryId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateModified()
    {
        return $this->dateModified;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getAuthUser()
    {
        return $this->authUser;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasChildCategories()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getChildCategories()->count();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     */
    public function getChildCategories()
    {
        return $this->childCategories;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasParentCategory()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getParentCategory();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function getParentCategory()
    {
        return $this->parentCategory;
    }

    public function hasProducts()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getProducts()->count();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\Sites
     */
    public function getSite()
    {
        return $this->site;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Application\Entity\StaticPages
     */
    public function getStaticPage()
    {
        return $this->staticPage;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return (bool) $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return strng
     */
    public function getUrlKey()
    {
        return $this->urlKey;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->sortOrder;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $category
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \DateTime  $dateCreated
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setDateCreated(\DateTime $dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateModified
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setDateModified(\DateTime $dateModified)
    {
        $this->dateModified = $dateModified;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\Sites $site
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setSite(\Application\Entity\Sites $site)
    {
        $this->site = $site;
        return $this;
    }

    public function hasStaticPage()
    {
        return (bool) $this->getStaticPage();
    }

        /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\StaticPages $staticPage
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setStaticPage(\Application\Entity\StaticPages $staticPage)
    {
        $this->staticPage = $staticPage;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStaticPage()
    {
        if ($this->getStaticPage() instanceof StaticPages) {
            $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
            $entityManager->remove($this->staticPage);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        $this->staticPage = NULL;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Users $authUser
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setAuthUser(\Application\Entity\Users $authUser)
    {
        $this->authUser = $authUser;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Application\Entity\Categories $parentCategory
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setParentCategory(\Application\Entity\Categories $parentCategory)
    {
        $this->parentCategory = $parentCategory;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param integer $active
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $urlKey
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setUrlKey($urlKey)
    {
        $escapeUri = $this->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('escapeUrl');
        $this->urlKey = $escapeUri($urlKey);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $description
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param integer $sortOrder
     * @return \Application\Entity\Categories
     */
    public function setSortOrder($sortOrder)
    {
        $this->sortOrder = $sortOrder;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $this->authUser = $this->getAutherizedUser();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @return \Application\Entity\Users
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->dateModified = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $array = array();
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $var => $value) {
            switch ($var) {
                case 'products':
                    foreach ($value as $product) {
                        $array[$var][] = $product->toArray();
                    }
                    break;
                case 'authUser':
                    if (!is_null($value)) {
                        $array[$var] = $value->toArray();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    $array[$var] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }

}
```

As can be seen the products and categories are linked through the table product_to_catagory.

I am using doctrines object multi checkbox to get the categories for the product using

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'categories',
            'type' => 'Admin\DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => _('Categories:'),
                'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'required'),
                'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
                'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\Categories',
                'property' => 'category',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'FindAll',
                ),
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            ),
        ));
```

The form is bound to the products entity

After the form is submitted the categories in the product entity returns Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection

The problem I am having is that the categories are not being saved on the database in the product_to_catagory table when I flush the products entity.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT
Changed owning side to products, code above updated.

Comment: please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913664/doctrine2-different-behaviours-on-removing-and-persisting-related-entities/31929938#31929938

Comment: Yes, check the docs for associations. Make sure before you persist, the categories are populated. If so, remove the form/element complexity from this question. All class variables should be protected type except the id which should be private. This is suggested by doctrine's hydrator.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have changed the owning side to products and set cascade to persist on both sides but the products to category are still not saving.

Comment: Got it working now, changing the owner side did work correctly.